# Build docker image, through docker-compose, using locally running verdaccio

Tags: docker, docker-compose, verdaccio

I'm running [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) locally (through docker) to publish private npm packages. I'm building one of my packages with Dockerfile which has:

```
RUN npm ci
```

in it. I'm actually building with `docker-compose`. I have a `.env` file to set these args:

```
        - NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY
        - NPM_CONFIG_USERNAME
        - NPM_CONFIG_EMAIL
        - NPM_CONFIG_PASSWORD
```

It is successfully trying to get packages from my local registry but it can't connect.

So my question is - how can I run `docker-compose build myservice` and have `myservice` use the locally running instance of `verdaccio` to pull packages from during the docker build?

EDIT: I'm running on a mac host.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working by adding a `network: host` entry under the `service`'s `build`:

```
    build:
      context: ./packages/server
      target: dev
      network: host
```

NOTE: giving some time to test this before accepting it as an answer (just in case as I've tried a number of other things to get this to work).

Comment: This is rarely necessary, and disables one of the core parts of Docker.  Often it's to work around a hard-coded `localhost` somewhere.  In the context of Docker for Mac, the magic host name `host.docker.internal` will refer to the physical host system (and host networking often doesn't work as you expect).

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks! I was able to remove the `network: host` in the build config and use the magic host name in my .env file: `NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=http://host.docker.internal:4873/`. The build is working as before. Could you add this as an answer? Do you know of a reference somewhere to "magic" host names for other host OSes? Or will `host.docker.internal` work elsewhere?